# Setting multiple variables from 1 line in text file

Tags: string, date, datetime, batch-file

I am using a sqlcmd to export 3 dates to a temp file, all 3 are in one line and i need to separate them
they are formatted as `[YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000]` for each one so the line in the text file looks like:

> ```
> [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000] [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000] [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000]
> ```

```
set /p date=< %tmp%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set st=%date%
set d1=!st:~0,19!
set d2=!st:~24,43!
set d3=!st:~48,67!

echo Date1 [%d1%]
echo Date2 [%d2%]
echo Date3 [%d3%]
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
```

When I run this it should output `[YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS]` for each date, which works for the first date.

The second date outputs as `[YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000 YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000]`, the first set is the second date and the second is the third date.

The third date is output is `[YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000]`, adding the `.000` even though the character count ends after the seconds.

Comment: using reserved variable `%tmp%` is a bad idea. open `cmd` and type `echo %tmp%` and you will see why. Anyway, how about showing me that date file. I cannot guess the current format.

Comment: 2020-01-20 12:00:01.000 2020-01-16 10:41:02.000 2020-01-18 16:49:05.000
thats the date format, and i set the %tmp% earlier in the file so its not the default.

Comment: __" and i set the %tmp% earlier in the file so its not the default."__ Yes I know, but `%tmp%` is a __reserved__ windows variable. open `cmd` type `echo %tmp%` and you will understand my point. Rather use `set mytmp` and then `%mytmp%` but do not use `%tmp%`

Answer (score 2):

by using the same file you are using now, but by changing the variable to `%mytmp%` due to `%tmp%` being a reserved system variable:

```
@echo off
set "mytmp=C:\path to temp\file.txt"
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,3,5" %%a in ("%mytmp%") do echo %%a %%b %%c
```

To utilize them the same as you did in your example (without the need to set variables):

```
@echo off
set "mytmp=C:\path to temp\file.txt"
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,3,5" %%a in ("%mytmp%") do (
    echo Date1 [%%a]
    echo Date2 [%%b]
    echo Date3 [%%c]
)
```

Comment: If you use `%%~Na`, `%%~Nb` and `%%~Nc` then the `.000` part in each date is _automatically_ deleted...

Comment: Thanks @Aacini. I will add that as an update. To be honest I should have asked OP to clarify if he wants date only or date and time excluding `.000` as the code seems to reference date and time but variable refers to date.